# how can i use regex in xpath 1.0

Tags: regex, xpath

this my xpath

```
//dns:tbody//dns:td[1][@rowspan="1"]/text()
```

I want to find a solution how can make the attribute rowspan `@rowspan=" only number "` accept just number

I'm looking for solution regular expression in XPath 1.0

Regexp =`^[0-9]*$`
my problem I don't know how to integrate the regex with XPath1.0 or any other solution

Comment: With XPath 1.0 you can't, although using regexes would be trivial with XPath 2.0. You could work around it using `number()`

Comment: my xpath will be like that `//dns:tbody//dns:td[1][@rowspan=number()]/text()`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below solution instead of regex:

```
//dns:tbody//dns:td[1][number(@rowspan)<=0 or number(@rowspan)>0]/text()
```

This should match `@rowspan` with int value

Comment: could you make it for n number?

Comment: By *"only number"* you mean any integer? Negative integer, zero? Any?

Comment: @MokiNex , how about `[number(@rowspan)<=0 or number(@rowspan)>0]`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a workaround that tests:

- if the text is a number (with the `number()` function)
- if the text doesn't start with `-` (with `starts-with()`)
- if the text doesn't contain the dot (with `contains()`)

like that:

```
//dns:tbody//dns:td[1][string(number(@rowspan))!='NaN'][not(starts-with(@rowspan, '-'))][not(contains(@rowspan, '.'))]/text()
```

or

```
//dns:tbody//dns:td[1][not(string(number(@rowspan))='NaN' or starts-with(@rowspan, '-') or contains(@rowspan, '.'))]/text()
```

Comment: I need to apply in the attribute rowspan

Answer (score 0):

Some XPath implementations allow you to supply your own functions. You will need to check the documentation on your XPath implementation.

Java: http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/xpath_apis.html#functionresolver

Comment: I'm not allowed to use the function just XPath because I'm using a workflow node accept just XPath query